# Why is my function not passing calculations properly?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a conversion calculator in JS and can’t figure out why my print function yields an output with “undefined” instead of a number based on calculations.

The point of the program is to ask the user to enter a weight and a planet they want to visit, perform a calculation based on the selected planet’s relative gravity, and print the new weight on that planet.

Here is a part of my code:

```js
// Ask for current weight input
let currentWeight = prompt('What is your current weight?');

// Ask for planet user wants to visit
let newPlanet = prompt('where do you want to visit?');

// function with input weight * relative gravity on selected planet 
// round answer to 2d
if (newPlanet === 'Earth' || newPlanet === 'earth') {
  return newWeight = (currentWeight * 1).toFixed(2);
}

// Calculated output
function calculation(currentWeight, newPlanet) {
  console.log('Your weight on ' + newPlanet + ' is ' + newWeight);
}

calculation(); // "Your weight on undefined is undefined"
// This is not the output I want.
```

Comment: Because `newWeight` is scoped inside your `ìf`. It's not a global variable.

Comment: Why there's a `return` statement outside of a function? Also `calculation` method is expecting 2 params but whereas it's being called without any params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some advices:

1- you don't use return statement outside a function

2- avoid naming the arguments of functions the same name as global variables

3- read this [article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript) to understand scopes better.

**Good Luck**

Check this code:

```js
// ask for current weight input
let currentWeight = prompt('What is your current weight?');

// ask for planet user wants to visit
let newPlanet = prompt('where do you want to visit?');

// function with input weight * relative gravity on selected planet 
// round answer to 2d

function newWeight () {
  if (newPlanet === 'Earth' || newPlanet === 'earth') {
    return (currentWeight * 1).toFixed(2);
  }
}

// calculated output
function calculation() {
    console.log('Your weight on '+ newPlanet + ' is ' + newWeight ());
}

calculation();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `calculation` could not access to your varibale `newWeight`.

You need to extract the variable from your function.

```js
// ask for current weight input
let currentWeight = prompt('What is your current weight?');

// ask for planet user wants to visit
let newPlanet = prompt('where do you want to visit?');

let newWeight = 0
// function with input weight * relative gravity on selected planet 
// round answer to 2d
if (newPlanet === 'Earth' || newPlanet === 'earth') {
    newWeight = (currentWeight * 1).toFixed(2);
}

// calculated output
function calculation(currentWeight, newPlanet) {
    console.log('Your weight on ' + newPlanet + ' is ' + newWeight);
}
calculation();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems

- There's a return statement outside of the function
- `newWeight` is not defined anywhere so it's being treated as a global variable and hence the value is being printed as `undefined`

```js
// calculated output
function calculation() {
  let currentWeight = prompt('What is your current weight?');

  // ask for planet user wants to visit
  let newPlanet = prompt('where do you want to visit?');
  let newWeight = currentWeight
  // function with input weight * relative gravity on selected planet 
  // round answer to 2d
  if (newPlanet === 'Earth' || newPlanet === 'earth') {
    newWeight = (currentWeight * 1).toFixed(2);
  }
  console.log('Your weight on ' + newPlanet + ' is ' + newWeight);
}
calculation();
```